# Are there any performance problems or limitations when using ShareDataset with BigQuery?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I'm planning database integration using ShareDataset on multiple GCP projects.

Is there any difference between the project-specific data and the data that shared data from other projects? ・ Expression of query and UTF ・response speed ・ limit of data that can be handled ・ Restriction on making a view

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand what you are concerned about. What performance problems? Are you worried that queries will take longer to run, or is there some other concern?

Comment: sorry, It was a bad question.
Is there any difference between the project-specific data and the data that shared data from other projects?
・ Expression of query and UTF
・response speed
・ limit of data that can be handled
・ Restriction on making a view

Comment: (・・) . . . . . .

Answer (score 0):

None of the points mentioned are affected by accessing data in different projects. When you run a query against some of the `bigquery-public-data` tables, for instance, the query will run in BigQuery's US multi-region, and it will access data from any of the replicas of the table. If you join this data with your own that is also in the US, BigQuery will execute the query in a cell where data from all referenced tables is available.

You would potentially notice increased client side latency from running a query e.g. from Hong Kong if the data is stored in London.

All of these things can be verified easily, though.